# Application of the spherical Radon transform property in tomography

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, signal-detection, transform

Let function $f$ be even and continuous on the unit sphere $S^n$. Let $R$-be a spherical Radon transform.

There is a known property:

$R(f^n)=f$ whenever $f$=constant.

What would this property mean in the tomograph?